# Multiple sound cards of the same brand?

Tags: sound-card, pci

I wish to build a home media server, which i am already half way through creating an application to stream media to different outputs. For the setup of the PC, i need 5 outputs in total (possibly one spare for future).

Will each sound card have to be a different make/model? Or can they be identical, i would prefer consistency over the sound.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PCI or PCI-e ? That's not the same, but they're related

Comment: PCI, I'm doing this on a budget and PCI-e sound cards are more pricey (especially when getting 4 or 5 of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. Your OS can tell the cards apart by the physical slot they're in.

With videocards, this is commonly done.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time I'd recommend going with the same make and model all the way, since that if a problem occurs it will be easier for you to fix.

Comment: All i meant was, if the motherboard / OS reconised 4/5 devices that are exactly the same, would it cause conflicts? Or would it show up as seperate devices?

This is my first time with something like this, but not my first time building a computer.